# How to show "Pay with a debit or credit card" button instead of "Checkout as Guest" on PayPal guest payment

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I have a project with a PayPal integration. On this, I have enabled the 'guest checkout option' in my PayPal account(U.S Account) for customers paying on my website. I need to show the "Pay with Debit or Credit Card" button always when a user opens the PayPal login page. But sometimes it showing the "Checkout as Guest" button instead of the "Pay with Debit or Credit Card" button.

How can I show the "Pay with Debit or Credit Card" button always? Does this have any relation with the browser cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control the behavior of the PayPal page. The behavior presented depends on very many factors--including, for example, the location of the buyer or repeated checkout attempts--and so is case by case. Sometimes the option to check out as a guest will not be available, at all.

If you want to always present a debit or credit card option, you should follow the [Set up standard payments guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/), which gives a black 'Debit or Credit Card' button.

---

If you have a server backend that can do API calls, then you should create two routes, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order' [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/) -- and pair your two routes with the [server approval flow](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server).

Comment: Thank you. Is this have any relation with the browser cookie?

Comment: It would not matter if it did