# PayPal Guest payment option not available on checkout

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to set up guest payment option on my Shopify checkout page and I followed the instruction that says to toggle on Pay Pal account optional (Website payments / Website preferences).

Despite I set up everything, the guest payment option isn't available again. I have a business account, bank account and debit business card have been linked to my PayPal account.

How can I make guest checkout available / how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not your own site/code, you won't be able to add a black Debit or Credit Card button (only Shopify can give an option to add it to their checkout page, and they don't want to), [this answer is otherwise current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64181112/how-to-show-pay-with-a-debit-or-credit-card-button-instead-of-checkout-as-gue).

Basically, you can't control the behavior further. Having Account Optional enabled is a necessary but not a sufficient condition for the PayPal Checkout to (decide to) include a guest option. Very many other factors also apply to the decision -- including, for example, the IP address and geographic location of the payer, among other things.